# To bring status bar in iphone 6 to normal size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am making an iphone application which is automatically getting autoresize in iphone 6 and 6s. But status bar is also getting zoomed because of which status bar is looking bigger than normal size. So I want to bring status bar to normal size. When I am using iphone 6 splash and default image it is not getting auto resize and black patch is coming on top and bottom of screen. So I want that app should autoresize status bar should not be zoomed and be .
Is there any other way to reduce the size of status bar.
Any Help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

[image: In screenshot the status bar is zoomed in iphone 6 using autolayout]

Comment: screenshot of what you are talking please...

Comment: Hi I had edit my question and put the screenshot i which status bar is zoomed.

Comment: what Default images you have in your app? AFAIK, you didn't include default images of iphone 6 and 6 plus bcz of which what you see is zoomed version of iphone 5s

Comment: Hi,Even I tried to put Default Image as well as launch image for 6 and 6s. But I think I am missing something please can you tell exact size and name of default images I should put in project.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change size of status bar. you can't customize it. Status bar's height is fixed 20 pixel in any device or resolution and it's width is same with screen's width.

So, You can't customize status bar.

now for splash screen issue, set imagview in `Launchscreen.storyboard` and set `top,bottom,leading and trailing` constraints to it